# re.search in Python 3 returns None

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My regex can't find a match for the pattern I'm searching for in a textfile. Here is my code:

```
myfile = ('_%s_Mail_%s.txt' % (timestr, emailid))

urls = re.search(r'^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$', myfile)
IPs = re.search(r'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$', myfile)
print(urls.group())
print(IPs.group())
```

this returns None

What's wrong with the expression?

Comment: Your regexes are searching the filename string, not the file itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not opening the file. You are applying the regex on the filename.

```
myfile = ('_%s_Mail_%s.txt' % (timestr, emailid))
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    urls = re.search(..., data)
```

Comment: I still returns "None" even though in my file i have several links like this: https://software.dell.com/docs/2015-dell-security-annual-threat-report-whit=e-paper-15657.pdf9

Comment: @user2331477: You should test your regex before using it: https://regex101.com/r/cC3yM2/2

Comment: Thank you for the tip, thats perfect!